# How to create a stylesheet with XML and XSL to transform into HTML content?

Tags: html, xml, stylesheet, xls

I need to link an XML file and an XSL in order to portray the information nicely in HTML format. I have linked the two files, however, when I open the XML file in the browser, nothing is displayed. The page is just blank. I have also made sure that the files names are correct

How do I get the information to display?

```
XML code: 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="Question2.xsl" type="text/xsl" ?>

<!DOCTYPE patronRecord [
<!ELEMENT patronRecord (Item*)>
<!ATTLIST patronRecord firstName CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST patronRecord lastName CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT Item (title,Authors,callNumber,due, overdue)>
<!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Authors (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT callNumber (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT due (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT overdue (#PCDATA)>

]>
<patronRecord firstName = "John" lastName = "Smith">
<Item>
 <title>Wireless network security</title>
 <Authors>T.Wrightson</Authors>
 <callNumber>212.12/56</callNumber>
 <due>26-12-2016</due>
 <overdue>NO</overdue>
</Item>
<Item>
 <title>T. Tao</title>
 <Authors>Analysis</Authors>
 <callNumber>515/305</callNumber>
 <due>23-12-2016</due>
 <overdue>NO</overdue>
</Item>
<Item>
 <title>The art of computer programming</title>
 <Authors>D.E. Knuth</Authors>
 <callNumber>005.1/300 </callNumber>
 <due>25-11-2016</due>
 <overdue>YES</overdue>
</Item>
<Item>
 <title>Python for dummies</title>
 <Authors>S. Maruch and A. Ranum</Authors>
 <callNumber>145.3/57</callNumber>
 <due>01-10-2016</due>
 <overdue>YES</overdue>
</Item>
</patronRecord>

XSL Code: 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="https://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match ="/patronRecord">
<html>
<body>
  <xsl:for-each select="Item">
    <xsl:value-of select="title" /><br/>
    <xsl:value-of select="Authors" /><br/>
    <xsl:value-of select="callNumber" /><br/>
    <xsl:value-of select="due" /><br/>
    <xsl:value-of select="overdue" /><br/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following change and get output:-

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="https://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

                                     **to**

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
```

Comment: That didn't do anything

Comment: @DrMe what you want output